# How to automagically create pattern based on real data?

Tags: regex, perl, pattern-matching

I have many vendors in database, they all differ in some aspect of their data. I'd like to make data validation rule which is based on previous data.

Example:

```
A: XZ-4, XZ-23, XZ-217
B: 1276, 1899, 22711
C: 12-4, 12-75, 12
```

Goal: if user inputs string 'XZ-217' for vendor B, algorithm should compare previous data and say: this string is not similar to vendor B previous data.

Is there some good way/tools to achieve such comparison? Answer could be some generic algoritm or Perl module.

Edit:
The "similarity" is hard to define, i agree. But i'd like to catch to algorithm, which could analyze previous ca 100 samples and then compare the outcome of analyze with new data. Similarity may based on length, on use of characters/numbers, string creation patterns, similar beginning/end/middle, having some separators in.

I feel it is not easy task, but on other hand, i think it has very wide use. So i hoped, there is already some hints.

Comment: This is really vague.  Try to define some things like "similar".  Computer can't say "Eh, that looks close enough" unless you give them precise rules.  For example, you could want "has more than X characters in common" or "starts with the same Y characters" or "has a the same symbol (e.g., dash) in the middle".

Comment: This is going to be quite difficult unless you can impose some additional constraints. Consider: how to keep your pattern-learning algorithm from deciding to use `qr/.*/`?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to peruse:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_metric and http://search.cpan.org/dist/Text-Levenshtein/Levenshtein.pm (for instance)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my implementation and a loop over your test cases. Basically you give a list of good values to the function and it tries to build a regex for it.

output:

```
A: (?^:\w{2,2}(?:\-){1}\d{1,3})
B: (?^:\d{4,5})
C: (?^:\d{2,2}(?:\-)?\d{0,2})
```

code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use List::MoreUtils qw'uniq each_arrayref';

my %examples = (
  A => [qw/ XZ-4 XZ-23 XZ-217 /],
  B => [qw/ 1276 1899 22711 /],
  C => [qw/ 12-4 12-75 12 /],
);

foreach my $example (sort keys %examples) {
  print "$example: ", gen_regex(@{ $examples{$example} }) || "Generate failed!", "\n";
}

sub gen_regex {
  my @cases = @_;

  my %exploded;

  # ex. $case may be XZ-217
  foreach my $case (@cases) {
    my @parts = 
      grep { defined and length } 
      split( /(\d+|\w+)/, $case );

    # @parts are ( XZ, -, 217 )

    foreach (@parts) {
      if (/\d/) {
        # 217 becomes ['\d' => 3]
        push @{ $exploded{$case} }, ['\d' => length];

      } elsif (/\w/) {
        #XZ becomes ['\w' => 2]
        push @{ $exploded{$case} }, ['\w' => length];

      } else {
        # - becomes ['lit' => '-']
        push @{ $exploded{$case} }, ['lit' => $_ ];

      }
    }
  }

  my $pattern = '';

  # iterate over nth element (part) of each case
  my $ea = each_arrayref(values %exploded);
  while (my @parts = $ea->()) {

    # remove undefined (i.e. optional) parts
    my @def_parts = grep { defined } @parts;

    # check that all (defined) parts are the same type
    my @part_types = uniq map {$_->[0]} @def_parts;
    if (@part_types > 1) {
      warn "Parts not aligned\n";
      return;
    }
    my $type = $part_types[0]; #same so make scalar

    # were there optional parts?
    my $required = (@parts == @def_parts);

    # keep the values of each part
    # these are either a repitition or lit strings
    my @values = sort uniq map { $_->[1] } @def_parts;

    # these are for non-literal quantifiers
    my $min = $required ? $values[0] : 0;
    my $max = $values[-1];

    # write the specific pattern for each type
    if ($type eq '\d') {
      $pattern .= '\d' . "{$min,$max}";

    } elsif ($type eq '\w') {
      $pattern .= '\w' . "{$min,$max}";

    } elsif ($type eq 'lit') {
      # quote special characters, - becomes \-
      my @uniq = map { quotemeta } uniq @values;
      # join with alternations, surround by non-capture grouup, add quantifier
      $pattern .= '(?:' . join('|', @uniq) . ')' . ($required ? '{1}' : '?');
    }
  }


  # build the qr regex from pattern
  my $regex = qr/$pattern/;
  # test that all original patterns match (@fail should be empty)
  my @fail = grep { $_ !~ $regex } @cases;

  if (@fail) {
    warn "Some cases fail for generated pattern $regex: (@fail)\n";
    return '';
  } else {
    return $regex;
  }
}
```

To simplify the work of finding the pattern, optional parts may come at the end, but no required parts may come after optional ones. This could probably be overcome but it might be hard.

Answer (score 1):

Joel and I came up with similar ideas. The code below differentiates 3 types of zones.

1. one or more non-word characters
2. alphanumeric cluster
3. a cluster of digits

It creates a profile of the string and a regex to match input. In addition, it also contains logic to expand existing profiles. At the end, in the task sub, it contains some pseudo logic which indicates how this might be integrated into a larger application.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util qw<max min>;

sub compile_search_expr { 
    shift;
    @_ = @{ shift() } if @_ == 1;
    my $str 
        = join( '|'
              , map { join( ''
                           , grep { defined; } 
                             map  {
                                 $_ eq 'P' ? quotemeta;
                               : $_ eq 'W' ? "\\w{$_->[1],$_->[2]}"
                               : $_ eq 'D' ? "\\d{$_->[1],$_->[2]}"
                               :             undef
                               ;
                            } @$_ 
                          )
                } @_ == 1 ? @{ shift } : @_
        );
    return qr/^(?:$str)$/;
}

sub merge_profiles {
    shift;
    my ( $profile_list, $new_profile ) = @_;
    my $found = 0;
    PROFILE:
    for my $profile ( @$profile_list ) { 
        my $profile_length = @$profile;

        # it's not the same profile.
        next PROFILE unless $profile_length == @$new_profile;
        my @merged;
        for ( my $i = 0; $i < $profile_length; $i++ ) { 
            my $old = $profile->[$i];
            my $new = $new_profile->[$i];
            next PROFILE unless $old->[0] eq $new->[0];
            push( @merged
                , [ $old->[0]
                  , min( $old->[1], $new->[1] )
                  , max( $old->[2], $new->[2] ) 
                  ]);
        }
        @$profile = @merged;
        $found = 1;
        last PROFILE;
    }
    push @$profile_list, $new_profile unless $found;
    return;
}

sub compute_info_profile { 
    shift;
    my @profile_chunks
        = map { 
              /\W/ ? [ P => $_ ]
            : /\D/ ? [ W => length, length ]
            :        [ D => length, length ]
        }
        grep { length; } split /(\W+)/, shift
        ;
}

# Psuedo-Perl
sub process_input_task { 
    my ( $application, $input ) = @_;

    my $patterns = $application->get_patterns_for_current_customer;
    my $regex    = $application->compile_search_expr( $patterns );

    if    ( $input =~ /$regex/ ) {}
    elsif ( $application->approve_divergeance( $input )) {
        $application->merge_profiles( $patterns, compute_info_profile( $input ));
    }
    else { 
        $application->escalate( 
           Incident->new( issue    => INVALID_FORMAT
                        , input    => $input
                        , customer => $customer 
                        ));
    }

    return $application->process_approved_input( $input );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there was a `Tie::StringApproxHash` module, it would fit the bill here.

I think you're looking for something that combines the fuzzy-logic functionality of [`String::Approx`](https://metacpan.org/module/String%3a%3aApprox) and the hash interface of [`Tie::RegexpHash`](https://metacpan.org/module/Tie%3a%3aRegexpHash).

The former is more important; the latter would make light work of coding.